# How to iterate over List<int[]> using Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have

```
List<int[]> allNumList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am iterating over `allNumList` and matching one condition in below code .

```
for (int[] arr : allNumList) {
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i == numb) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do above code using Java 8.

Answer (score 19):

```
boolean noMatch = allNumList.stream()
    .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
    .noneMatch(i -> i == numb);
```

Comment: I don't find this answer useful since no description is included. Just a code is not an answer. Why `flatMapToInt`? Why `noneMatch`? OP has NO idea about them apparently.

Comment: @Nikolas since the OP didn’t show even the slightest attempt of doing it on their own, there’s even the possibility that the OP doesn’t know what `stream()` does. Explaining every operation and even the concepts behind it, is way too much for Stackoverflow. That’s why in the old days, such a question was closed without an answer. But these are the new days, were we are supposed to be welcoming and comments asking “did you read the manual?” or “what have you tried?” are considered impolite. So the best answer is a code drop in the hope, that the OP will do the research *now* using the pointers.

Comment: @Nikolas I wasn't sure whether to answer the question at all, because (as Holger pointed out) the OP didn't describe what he tried. Finally, however, I decided the question was so simple I might as well drop some code, and the OP should be able to at least figure out what it does by himself.

Comment: @Holger I wasn't sure whether this is a "closeable" question or not, so I just gave it a shot. However, I certainly don't feel like this answer deserves the +13 votes that it got so far.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski when I was new at Stackoverflow, I was baffled by the distribution of the votes, too. There are too many nontechnical factors involved, so the votes are not proportional to the actual quality of the posts, however, they become much more reasonable on a larger scale, say, when you have thousand answers or more.

Comment: Yes, it’s a very good snippet of code, I upvoted it myself. I agree that +13 is very overrated, however SO is unpredictable. Only I try to say that the isolated code with no description, comments is not good (the same in the real development). At least two lines of info would help understand why to use this code is a good way.

Comment: @Nikolas In the real development, the code would sit inside a method whose name would say what it does :) Unfortunately, the OP didn't provide such context.

But I understand what you mean, and I try to follow such guidelines for less trivial questions.